# Activity sliding from bottom to top but background activity should not moved

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to slide an Activity from Bottom to Top which I am able to do.

But while sliding from bottom to top my background activity is also sliding to bottom.
I want to keep background activity to same position as it was, so that the new activity will seem as a overlay to background activity when open.

Here are my slide_in_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

and slide_out_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

How can I do that?
Thanks...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Then provide an outgoing animation to make the current Activity stay still:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.stay);
```

stay.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

Comment: Nope.... Actually the background activity gets finishes while new activity is sliding up

Comment: Thanks... It worked... Actually when we are using 0 the background activity getting finished and new activity getting displayed.
But using above xml now it worked as I want.

Answer (score 56):

> slide_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

</set>
```

> slide_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

> stay.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

> Open Activity

```
startActivity(new Intent(FromActivity.this, ToActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.stay);
```

> Close Activity

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.stay, R.anim.slide_down);
```

Comment: Works for me.  `
change on this line overridePendingTransition(R.anim.stay, R.anim.slide_down);`

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, That is the perfect and detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply call `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, 0)`

`0` means no animation.

Comment: I think 0 here means “default” (in API 26+ at least), so you get a black background or rather a background with your window color.