# How to get slide up and down transition filter in android

Tags: android

Does any one know or any reference site to which shows how to achieve this feature? Is it implemented Fragment?
I would like to get the Zomato example from the below link.

[image]

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/75333/best-practice-for-android-actionbar-filtration

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: Probably duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603988/activity-sliding-from-bottom-to-top-but-background-activity-should-not-moved)

Comment: thanks @FarshidABZ ... How to get that kind filter into my action bar? I have basic text search button as of now. Would like to provide that slidable filter next to basic filter with similar check boxes.

Comment: @user1130456 I don't know what "filter into action bar" means. but if you want to show a view that contains a custom toolbar and a RecycleView in it, and use it everywhere. you can use BottomDialogFragment

Answer (score 0):

I guess this so basic , this would have caused ambiguity. 
Get another button to the action bar and associate this filter icon to an Activity , this activity can have multiple check boxes to fulfil my requirement.